# Can I buy the expansions from Steam if my copy of Sims 3 wasn't bought from Steam?

Tags: steam, the-sims-3

I already own Sims 3 and Sims 3 Generations after buying them from Best Buy and Walmart. If I want to buy other expansions through the Steam sales, do I have to rebuy these two in order to play them? Or will they work with the Sims 3 games that I already own?

Comment: i couldnt figure out a way to make it work

Answer (score 3):

You need to own the base game on Steam for it to work.

It actually says this on the Steam page when you look at the expansion packs:

> Requires the base game The Sims™ 3 on Steam in order to play.

So yes you will need to rebuy the games on Steam if you want to purchase expansions on Steam.

Answer (score -2):

Not necessarily.  If it's eligible for Steam key you can enter the key into steam. Take the product key from both the games you got at best buy, and try to enter them into steam. If its an applicable game..then it'll basically use that key to register the game(s) with Steam and then you will have them unlocked in Steam without having to buy them.

This link explains how to do this: https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=5414-TFBN-1352

Comment: Sims 3 is not on the list of games that support this https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=7480-WUSF-3601

Comment: And also, if you already used the key somewhere else. Steam will probably see the key as used.

Comment: @SirKsilem unlikely.